# How to load multiple template files using requireJs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using **Require JS** to load vendor files and templates in JS.

I want to call one function when all related templates are loaded in page.

Currently I need to nested call like below:

```
requirejs(['text!templates/stream/leaderboard_m.ejs'], function(Leaderboard_M) 
{
      requirejs(['text!templates/stream/leaderboard_tl.ejs'], function(Leaderboard_TL) {

                    loadLeadrboardData(Leaderboard_M, Leaderboard_TL);

   });
});
```

I would like to do that in 1 statement:

How can I do that using require JS?

Comment: why can't you `require([text!blah-blah-first.ejs', 'text!blah-blah-second.ejs], function(first, second){ load(first, second);});` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep

This would be what you want:

```
define([
    "./services/MyFirstService",
    "./services/MySecondService",
    "./services/MyThirdService",
], 
function (
    MyFirstService, 
    MySecondService, 
    MyThirdService
) {
    // all files loaded and can be used now!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to this:

```
requirejs(['text!templates/stream/leaderboard_m.ejs',
           'text!templates/stream/leaderboard_tl.ejs'],
           loadLeadrboardData);
```

All items in the list passed to the `require` (aka. `requirejs`) call are loaded before the callback is loaded. And the callback is loaded with the result of each item in the list of dependencies, in the same order. So you can have `requirejs` call `loadLeadrboardData` directly.

(I'd expect the function to be properly spelled `loadLeaderboardData`, not `loadLeadrboardData` with a missing `e`, but this is tangential to the problem asked here.)